# Full remote access to android device with stealth mode

Tags: android

Hi I need to be able to remote access one of my android phones from either pc or another android device but I need it to be in some form of stealth mode.  The app just needs to be hidden really but if complete stealth is possible the even better.

Comment: So you don't want to tell yourself that you invade your device? What's the use-case for that? What's the real issue behind?

Comment: Its my daughters phone and since its on my account and i pay the bill technically its my fone

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Cerberus Anti Theft](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsdroid.cerberus&hl=en), it can be installed and prevented from being uninstalled with a password and hidden from the app drawer. It allows viewing of the phones current location and location history, sending alerts to the phone, viewing the screen and cameras, locking out of the device, changing of passwords, viewing text and call details and much more. The app offers a free trial with payed full version. A single payed version supports multiple phones/devices and they provide a viewer app for checking on your other devices.